# Printing variable and text without space?

Tags: php

I have the following php code:

```
$mem=10;
echo "Memory: $mem MB<br>";
```

Which prints out:

```
Memory: 10 MB
```

I would like it to print out:

```
Memory: 10MB
```

I can't do this:

```
echo "Memory: $memMB<br>";
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Concatenation is in about every PHP Beginners tutorial, I have recommended [phpacademy to friends who just started in PHP, they loved it. You might want to check it out](https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy/playlists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using concatenation is an easy way:

```
echo "Memory: ".$mem."MB<br>";
```

Comment: @Jake: there is a time-limit to accepting answers, be patient

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Memory: {$mem}MB<br>";
```

note that this work even with multi level arrays, or objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commas with `echo`:

```
echo "Memory: ", $mem, "MB<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways, but IMHO, the best is:

```
printf('Memory: %dMB<br>', (int) $mem);//drop the cast if you so desire
```

That just looks clean, to me. In addition, using formatted output strings allows for a lot more control (ie: `printf("Value: %.2f", 123.23213);` will output `Value: 123.23`)
Alternatives would be:

```
echo 'Memory: ', $mem, '<br>';//comma's, because echo is a language construct
echo 'Memory: '.$mem.'<br>';//concatenate if you want
```

Or: use brackets to disambiguate the expression:

```
echo "Memory: {$mem}MB <br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation,

```
echo 'Memory: '.$mem.'MB<br>';
```

Or else, this would also work,

```
echo "Memory: {$mem}MB<br>";
```

This is to separate your variable from the surrounding text.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $mem=10;
    // you can do this because ther $mem is varibale 
    echo "Memory: $mem MB<br>";


    /*
        but here you cannot do this because Here $memMB act as a variable which 
        you not decleared give an error :  Notice: Undefined variable: memMB 
    */
    echo "Memory: $memMB<br>"; 

    /*
        For out put Memory: 10MB
    */
        echo "Memory:".$mem."MB"."<br />";
?>
```